# Error in model.frame.default : variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

Tags: regression, variance

When I am trying to do WLS to correct for heteroskedasticity, I for the following error:

Do you have any suggestions? I noticed that my regression has list length of 13 and the vector for W has 14. I am not sure how to correct for this.

```
W <- 1 / lm(abs(R40$residuals) ~ R40$fitted.values)$fitted.values^2

R40w <- lm(Market_Cap ~ MarketCap_Lag + Value_traded_ratio + GDP_growthR, data=pdata, weights = W)
summary(R40w)


Error in model.frame.default(formula = Market_Cap ~ MarketCap_Lag + Value_traded_ratio +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
```

Comment: I looked for similar problems, but nothing helped.

Comment: can you include the full code, including libraries etc and is this done in R?

Comment: can you edit your question? thanks

Comment: I just did. Is it okay? Yes, it is in R.

Comment: no way to reproduce your error. we don't have R40 or R40w. my guess is there is NA inside pdata so you end up with different lengths

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: R40 is my regression without WLS, where R40W is with WLS. And also, there is no NA inside my data for sure.